# sIFR not working on any browser

Tags: sifr, invisible

This is my first time using sIFR3 436. I have followed the instructions and cannot get the text to render at all.

http://investcielo.com

I'm using both h1 and h2 tags and it will not work. They're still hidden. I'm sure it's something simple, possibly in the css, but I can't find it. I've been looking at it for too long and maybe some more experienced and "fresh" eyes can see something I can't. Thanks.

FWIW, the original text doesn't show either. It's blank. sIFR doesn't render anything and the original text is gone too.

Answer (score 1):

The Flash movie seems to be corrupted. Opening it in a browser should display 'Rendered with sIFR r436', but it's blank.

Comment: OK, after a I exported a few different fonts I was finally able to get one working. However, I can't debug it now.

Comment: var diavlo = {
src: 'http://investcielo.com/assets/js/diavlo.swf'
};

sIFR.activate(diavlo);

sIFR.debug.ratios({ src: 'diavlo.swf', selector: 'h1,h2' });

/*sIFR.replace(diavlo, {
  selector: 'h1', 

});*/

Comment: OK, I finally figured it out. I can't debug two selectors at the same time. I did one at a time and now it's working. Thanks.